# How to turn this cold observable into hot?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I can't seem to be able to turn this cold observable into a hot one:

```
const test = new BehaviorSubject('test').pipe(tap(() => console.log('I want this to be logged only once to the console!')))

const grr = test.pipe(
  share(), // share() seems to not do anything
  take(1), // The culprit is here, causes logging to take place 5 times (5 subscribers)
  share() // share() seems to not do anything
)

grr.subscribe(() => console.log(1))
grr.subscribe(() => console.log(2))
grr.subscribe(() => console.log(3))
grr.subscribe(() => console.log(4))
grr.subscribe(() => console.log(5))

// Expected output:
// 'I want this to be logged only once to the console!'
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
```

How should I change this to produce the wanted output?

Comment: `test` is already hot. A `BehaviorSubject` - by design - emits its current vale to new subscribers. If you do not want that, use a `Subject` instead.

Comment: I need it to be a BehaviorSubject elsewhere, but here I want to convert it and I tried using share(). Typically share() has worked for me in many cases like this. Share uses Subject under the hood.

Comment: `skip(1)` if you don't want the current value.

Comment: That's not what I need. I need the subscribe functions to run, but the console log happen only once. I.e. I want multiple observers with the event happening only once. @cartant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `publishReplay` and `refCount` operators like this:

```
import { interval, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { publishReplay, tap, refCount } from 'rxjs/operators';

const test = new BehaviorSubject('test').
                  pipe(
                    tap(() => console.log('I want this to be logged only once to the console!')
                    ),
                    publishReplay(1),
                    refCount()
                  );

test.subscribe(() => console.log(1));
test.subscribe(() => console.log(2));
test.subscribe(() => console.log(3));
test.subscribe(() => console.log(4));
```

Working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cvcmq6?file=index.ts

Comment: How is this different from shareReplay()?

Comment: You can use `shareReplay` for the same purpose [I also used to use that until I found a bug in rxjs ver 6.2.2; https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3336#issuecomment-416252839] but keep in mind that `shareReplay` keeps the subscription running even if you unsubscribe the subscription [at least in ver. 6.2.2]. I have updated the same stackblitz to show the behavior of `shareReplay`. I did not test `shareReplay` on the latest version (It requires to use some config). To avoid memory leaks I started to use `publishReplay(1),refCount()`.

Comment: @user2216584 this was fixed, so `shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })` will do the same, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sharereplay-config

Comment: @OlesSavluk Thanks for letting me aware!